# How to select a particular record from database(SQLite) in android?

Tags: android, sqlite

Hello Everyone I am very new bee in android, so I am little confused on retrieving data from table... Should i use **put**(cv.put(DatabaseHelper.TITLE, title);) or **get**(cv.get(DatabaseHelper.TITLE, title);) to retrieve data from my class. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer `get` to retrieve data

for more info Check below link:

Its explaining all basics about sqlite dataabse with android

http://droidreign.com/2010/10/dev-tutorials-android-sqlite-database-basics/

Answer (score 1):

My best answer based on the information provided:

Use **get** to retrieve, i.e., get, data.

Also, take a look at [the notepad tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html) for a decent introduction to using databases from an Android app.